# Why do I suddenly have a bouncing Python rocket?

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, backend

Recently, I made a simple change to some matplotlib code I run on OS X (10.10; Python 2.7.6), commenting out a single line that set the backend I use

```
#matplotlib.use('agg')
```

Now, as long as my code is running, I get a bouncing Python icon in my dock, that presents no UI and only offers ***Force Quit...*** as an command:

[image]

Generally dock icons that continue bouncing without any UI are a "bad thing". Why am I getting this and is it something I should be concerned about?

Answer (score 2):

Not a "bad thing". The icon appears in the dock when Python interacts with the GUI. [Agg](http://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#generate-images-without-having-a-window-appear) is a non-interactive backend. With `agg` you did not see the icon since there was no Python UI interaction.