# what do jumping rockets mean when running a python script?

Tags: python, macos

I am working on a simple flask app. When I run it from my shell using python2 controller.py it works, but 2 jumping rockets appear on the bottom of my screen (I am using Mac).

[image]

Does it mean anything? It is strange for me since I often use python, but have never seen
something like this.

Comment: Possibly related: http://leancrew.com/all-this/2014/01/stopping-the-python-rocketship-icon/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26680509/why-do-i-suddenly-have-a-bouncing-python-rocket

Answer (score 1):

This means that your Python interpreter has attempted to interact with the GUI.

You can do this from your own scripts quite easily. For instance, you can run the [Hello, tkinter](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-hello-tkinter.htm) example from the upstream docs:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
w = Label(root, text="Hello, world!")
w.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Without knowing which libraries your Flask app uses, it's hard to say why it might have triggered this behavior. That said, you might look through `sys.modules.keys()` to see which Python libraries have been imported -- any GUI library will let you know this has happened; you can then bisect your imports (putting the code that checks `sys.modules` at different locations in the import section of your script) to see where it's happening.